# Date difference timer of current and past date in android

Tags: android, date, timer

I am trying to make a difference between current and past date which I am getting perfectly. But what I want is with the timer like if my Current time is 1:02 and my past time is 12:02 then my timer should give me a result like: 01:02:02, 01:00:03, 01:00:03,01:00:04.
I know its not that much complicated problem but I am not able to find a solution for it. Right now code which I am working is given below:

```
        try {
                Date currentSystemClockTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

                long diff = currentSystemClockTime() - serverDateTime.getTime();
                long seconds = diff / 1000;
                long minutes = seconds / 60;
                long hours = minutes / 60;
                long days = hours / 24;

                txtTimer.setText(days+"D:"+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds+"");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have a background thread that calls your code every 1 second.

Comment: so basically you want to generate timer between past date and current date ?

Comment: Have a Handler to handle this. and give 10000 as wait time.

Comment: @TDG thanks for your message. Currently I am getting output like this: 0D:1:62:3762 means Day=0, Hours =1, Minutes =62 and seconds = 3762.. But I want to display a difference between with current time and server time for example if it is 1.5 hours back then it should be like: 0D:1:32:00, 0D:1:32:01, 0D:1:32:02

Comment: @HarinKaklotar thanks for your message. I want to make a difference from current time and past time. Means how many hours I did something and clock should show time ticking as well. For example if I did something 1 hour 2 minutes back (Server Time) then with current time difference it should show something like  1:00:00, 1:00:01,1:00:02,1:00:03.....

Comment: @UKhan oh it's easy man you can use android CountDownTimer class with some modification. by using you don't need to car about background thread or anything else.

Comment: @HarinKaklotar thanks for your quick response. Can you please give me code snippet for better explanation. But one thing this time is not backward, its a forward timer means how many Hours,Minutes sort of difference from the Date you started.

Comment: @HarinKaklotar in CountDownTimer they have something onFinish() method. But in my condition there is no limitation of time. Means if my previous time/date is 2 hours back then it should show means increasing numbers like: 1:00:00,1:00:01,1:00:02.... so on.

Comment: yup that what I want to tell you. In the **CountDownTimer** class handler is *decrease* with one so we can create one custom class which can pass the past time in millisecond and in handler we **increase** with one. with that we need one listener which can display that millisecond time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem, I am putting an answer here for other people information. I made a method which will calculate date difference in Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds along with the timer.

Method for calculating Date Difference:

```
public void checkingCondition(){

        if(ParseUser.getCurrentUser()!=null && ParseUser.getCurrentUser().has("scanTime")){

          final  Date scanDateTime = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getDate("scanTime");

            Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

            try {
                long diff = now.getTime() - scanDateTime.getTime();

                long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
                long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                System.out.print(diffDays + " days, ");
                System.out.print(diffHours + " hours, ");
                System.out.print(diffMinutes + " minutes, ");
                System.out.print(diffSeconds + " seconds.");

                if(diffDays == 0){
                    String hours = "", minutes = "", seconds = "";
                    if(diffHours < 10){
                        hours = "0"+diffHours;
                    }else{
                        hours = ""+diffHours;
                    }
                    if(diffMinutes < 10){
                        minutes = "0"+diffMinutes;
                    }else{
                        minutes = ""+diffMinutes;
                    }
                    if(diffSeconds < 10){
                        seconds = "0"+diffSeconds;
                    }else{
                        seconds = ""+diffSeconds;
                    }
                    txtTimer.setText(hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);


                }else{
                    String hours = "", minutes = "", seconds = "";
                    if(diffHours < 10){
                        hours = "0"+diffHours;
                    }else{
                        hours = ""+diffHours;
                    }
                    if(diffMinutes < 10){
                        minutes = "0"+diffMinutes;
                    }else{
                        minutes = ""+diffMinutes;
                    }
                    if(diffSeconds < 10){
                        seconds = "0"+diffSeconds;
                    }else{
                        seconds = ""+diffSeconds;
                    }
                    txtTimer.setText(diffDays+"D "+hours+":"+minutes+":"+seconds);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Handler method for timer:

```
try {
            final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();

            updater = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        checkingCondition();

                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    timerHandler.postDelayed(updater,500);
                }
            };
            timerHandler.post(updater);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
```